# Largest ball with fixed center in a a convex region

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Let $x_0$ be a point contained inside a compact, convex set $C\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, which is of the form $C=\{x:f(x)\leq0\}$ for some explicit convex function $f$.  Is there a computationally tractable way to find the largest ball, centered at $x_0$, that is contained inside $C$?  When $C$ is a polyhedron defined by linear inequalities, this problem is trivial (just check the minimum distance to the boundary of each of the half-spaces defined by the inequalities).

Comment: I think the computer tractability question would mainly depend on how $C$ is given. Do you have any "computer readable" representation in mind?

Comment: Let's say it's the sub-level set of a convex function, $\{x:f(x)\leq 0\}$?  Just edited the problem.

Comment: Try a coordinate system change: move $x_0$ to the origin and then use spherical coordinates.  See if you can use some analysis to find an optimal r.  Gerhard "Maybe Cylindrical Coordinates Will Work" Paseman, 2015.04.01

Comment: I think Alex's point is that your question cannot be answered without a description of *how* $C$ is given. As a semi-algebraic set?

Comment: This is a borderline useless comment, but if you're willing to consider a "ball" in the $\ell_1$ sense, then all you'd have to do is check each of its $2d$ vertices, which would enable you to just do a simple bisection search on the "radius" and treat $f$ as a black box.